# How can I display points with points displacement renderer without circleoutline

Tags: qgis, point, symbology

I understand the point displacement, but I would like to display the circle without the circleoutline. Even when I change the "circle pen width" to 0,00 it displays a fine line. And there is no transparent color. 
Do you have any ideas?

[image: point displacement]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The upcoming QGIS 2.12 release allows control over transparency for the circle. So you could try with one of the nightly/beta versions to get this right now, or wait until the final 2.12 release.

Comment: Ok thank you for this information you, that could be a solucion for the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

In "Kreisfarbe" option try out with the equivalent English option to "No Pen" for "Border Style". You can also select in **Simple Fill -> Border** the #ffffff html notation (white color background).

Comment: Sorry, but there is no option "No Pen" at Kreisfarbe (i'm using QGIS 2.8.1 Wien"). Or do I have to look at another place?
If I fill the "Kreisfarbe" with white, I have some problems in other parts of the map. Or where should I select "simple fill"?
(I added some screenshots above)